# Downloading text files only with wget

Tags: ftp, wget

Using `wget` is it possible to spider a host for a specific file type? I'm archiving some documents from an FTP and I need to have it crawl the entire host only downloading `.txt` files.

I've attempted like so:

```
wget mysite.com/ftplist --config=./.wgetrc
```

With the following `.wgetrc`:

```
accept = txt
check_certificate = off
connect_timeout = 3
cookies = off
dns_cache = off
follow_ftp = on
logfile = amz.log
max_redirect = 3
no_clobber = on
recursive = on
save_headers = on
```

This will make a call to `mysite.com/ftplist`. This page contains `ftp://` URL's in a list. `wget` makes a request to this page but won't proceed any further and seems to stop on that page.

Here is the `amz.log`

```
Saving to: ‘mysite.com/ftplinks/index.html.tmp’

 0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  656K
50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  741K
100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 1.12M
150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  975K
200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  935K
250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  835K
300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  870K
350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 1.07M
400K .......... .......... .......... .......                907K=0.5s

2018-12-20 17:55:54 (881 KB/s) - ‘mysite.com/ftplinks/index.html.tmp’ saved [447555]

Removing mysite.com/ftplinks/index.html.tmp since it should be rejected.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `wget -A "*.txt" -r`, https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-command-wget-2201085. giyf

Comment: I have accept and recursion set in the `.wgetrc`. I have tried `*.txt` using `accept = *.txt` to no avail. added output log. It only visits the first page and then stops. I have a feeling it's because there are no `.txt` files on the first page?

Comment: Have you tried to set depth to infinity ?